# Little gap between divs, but I have no margins set on css

Tags: html, css

Here's the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ztxmqyxg/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Apple - iPhone</title>
```

```
<ul>
    <img src="images/logo.png">
    <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">iPod</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ad">

    <h1>Think different</h1>

</div>
<div id="product-container">
    <div id="product" class="product2">



    </div>
    <div id="product" class="product1">



    </div>
</div>
<div id="product-container2">

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

ul img {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right:30px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}

li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#ad {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 200px;

}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: #EDEDED;
}

#product-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#product {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.product1 {
    background-color: #DAE7EB;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.product2 {
    background-color: ;
    width: 50%;
}

#product-container2 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
}
```

Well, in the JSfiddle there's a gap between the nav bar and the 2 first divs, that doesn't happen when I run it on my computer so don't mind that.

The problem is the gap between the white and blue boxes and the gray one on the bottom, as you see there's a small gap, but I don't see why that could be.

Actually I tried setting margin to 0 (to see if that worked) but it didn't.

Comment: It is caused by bootstrap if you add `margin: 0 !important;` to the `ul` the gap will disappear. It is probably because in local file, your css loads last and bootstrap's css are overridden but in jsfiddle it doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is for `display: inline-block` in #product div that cause to unwanted 5px margin. remove it and change .productcontainer to `display:flex`

```css
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

ul img {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right:30px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}

li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    color: #EDEDED;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 18px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#ad {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 200px;
    
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: #EDEDED;
}

#product-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

#product {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    height: 300px;
    
}

.product1 {
    background-color: #DAE7EB;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

.product2 {
    background-color: ;
    width: 50%;
}

#product-container2 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apple - iPhone</title>
    
</head>
    
<body>
    

    
    <ul>
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">iPod</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="ad">
    
        <h1>Think different</h1>
    
    </div>
    <div id="product-container">
        <div id="product" class="product2">
    
        
    
        </div>
        <div id="product" class="product1">
    
        
    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="product-container2">
        
    </div>

    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not the gap I want to remove, the gap is between the blueish div and the gray one, at the bottom. Here's an image of what I'm saying: http://image.prntscr.com/image/5b9041bd9952490f8fe76c58e3fdf0af.png

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! I'm starting with html and css (though I used it a bit some years ago) and sometimes it's difficult haha.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztxmqyxg/1/)

It was the line height causing the issue. Update your CSS for `#product-container` as follows

```
#product-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
        line-height: 0; //<--- Add this
}
```